# get exception integrating micrometer to elastic-search application

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, prometheus, spring-micrometer

I have a Spring-Boot application that calls to elastic-search cluster. I want to add prometheous monitoring to it. I have just add only 
 following dependencies,
 As soon as i run the application i get java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

```
     <!-- Spring boot actuator to expose metrics endpoint -->
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Micormeter core dependecy  -->
     <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry  -->
     <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

My error log is as follows

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.get(FutureUtils.java:72) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture.actionGet(AdapterActionFuture.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture.actionGet(AdapterActionFuture.java:44) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(ElasticsearchHealthIndicator.java:80) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:84) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:98) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:50) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:246) [spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:61) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:126) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:99) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809) [?:?]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [?:?]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) [?:?]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) [?:?]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) [?:?]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827) [?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359) [?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562) [?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796) [?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:235) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.get(FutureUtils.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Could you describe your environment? It seems that the elasticsearch/prometheus host can't be reached

Comment: I'm Application in localhost, Prometheus running on localhost. elastic search in another server

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace seems to indicate that the `ElasticsearchHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck` task `Timeout waiting for task.`. This often occurs if no connection could be established. You mentioned the elastic search service is running on an external server. Could you check if the program has access to the Elasticsearch port on the server?

Elasticsearch is restricted to localhost by default, because if this no external programs can access it.

Comment: After I run elastic-search locally. it works thank you

Comment: Could you mark this solution as answer so other people can find it? @DamithaDayananda

Answer (score 0):

After I connect elastic-search running in local problem was solved. As I guess the reason to issue is bad connectivity. And nothing relate to micrometer